# Convergence of Remainder from Taylor Expansion

Tags: analysis, statistics, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, self-learning

For a distribution function $F$ and its variance functional $T(F)$, it can be shown that the Taylor expansion of $T(F)$ at $F$ in the direction of the empirical distribution function $F_n$ gives the remainder $$R_{1n} = -(\bar X - \mu)^2,$$ where $n$ is the sample size and $1$ means there is only the linear term in Taylor expansion. By the law of iterated logarithm, it is true that $$|R_{1n}| = O(n^{-1}\log\log n)\ a.s.$$ Then it is claimed that $$\sqrt{n} R_{1n} \to 0$$ ***in probability***. Why is this the case, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{n} R_{1n} = -\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)^2 = [\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)]\cdot (\bar X - \mu)$$

$$[\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)] \xrightarrow{d} N(0,\sigma^2), \;\;(\bar X - \mu)\xrightarrow{p}0$$

Then, apply Slustky's Theorem (which does not require *distinct* random variables).

Comment: Thanks. However, from Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem, the resulting product converges to $0$ in distribution instead of in probability. Do you suggest convergence in distribution implies convergence in probability?

Comment: Have you noticed that the one component converges to the constant $0$? Then the whole expression converges in distribution to zero, i.e. to a constant  and  _then_ it is equivalent to convergence in probability.

Comment: Because it is a degenerate case, i.e. no longer a random variable in the strict sense. Right?

Comment: Yes it is only a "degenerate" random variable. But that does not make the concept of convergence in distribution invalid: it just means that the distribution function converges to a constant.

Comment: Sorry, what I was trying to ask is that convergence in distribution implies convergence in probability here because of the degenerate case. Otherwise, in general, we do not have convergence in distribution implying convergence in probability. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: I just realized that we have not use the LIL result given in the question. Or maybe I did not see how it was use. Do you happen to know, please?

Comment: @20824 No, and I don't see why it would be needed here.